# Magento 2 migeration

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-block

i was able to successfully migrate from 1.9 to magento 2 using  data migration tool, from github. the tools migrates everything except for cms pages, and cms blocks. I dump the pages and blocks tables from old db to new db, but i am getting an error related to duplicate primary key. i am not good with sql queries - what is the  best way to dump this data?

Answer (score 0):

try to run

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  table_name;
```

on your cms tables.. and the run the import again

Comment: TRUNCATE would delete the table completely, no? it looks like my old db tables have prefix.

Comment: No truncate will clear the table, the table structure will stay

Comment: i got the error - primary key cannot be TRUNCATE